# How to console input and store a line of numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, split, numbers

There is a line full of a specific (N) of numbers.
For example:
if N = 5 then the line can be:

0 1 5 3 4

How can I read in a line like that? If I store it in a string (string temp; cin >> temp;), it becomes '00' for some reason... Also, I need to put them into a number array. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Show a [mcve] of what you've tried and note what specifically you need help with.

Comment: [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 0):

There a plethora of posts, on StackOverflow, that read a line of numbers from an online judge.

Here is an example:

```
int number;
int quantity;
std::vector<int> database;
std::cin >> quantity;
for (int index = 0; index < quantity; ++index)
{
  std::cin >> number;
  database.push_back(number);
}
```

If you are allergic to, or have an aversion to `std::vector`, you can try creating a dynamic array:

```
int number;
int quantity;
int * database;
std::cin >> quantity;
database = new int[quantity];
for (int index = 0; index < quantity; ++index)
{
    std::cin >> number;
    database[index] = number;
}
// Use database
delete[] database; // return the allocated memory.
```